# Hadoop reports wrong file size

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop seems to be reporting the wrong file size for a file that's still in progress (i.e. an open file handle exists):

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /spark_event_log/application_1455759060111_0228.inprogress
16/02/29 20:56:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-rwxrwx---   2 user supergroup        235 2016-02-29 20:24 /spark_event_log/application_1455759060111_0228.inprogress
$ hadoop fs -cp /spark_event_log/application_1455759060111_0228.inprogress /spark_event_log/test.inprogress
16/02/29 20:57:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
$ hadoop fs -ls /spark_event_log/test.inprogress
16/02/29 20:58:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-rw-r--r--   2 user supergroup       6809 2016-02-29 20:39 /spark_event_log/test.inprogress
```

What's going on here?

Comment: .inprogress files in spark is created while processing , so sometimes the file size might vary, also there are some issue with this .inprogress files listed in JIRA to be fixed in next release